# ¿Qué hago si no me aparece reporting services en windows form c# en visual studio community 2017?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

No me aparece  reporting services en windows form c# en visual studio community 2017

Answer (score 1):

Puede agregarlo como extension

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma tendras los template para crear reportes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Install RDLC Extensions In Visual Studio 2017](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/install-rdlc-extensions-in-visual-studio-2017/)